# Unable to get WCF Test client to test WCF Service Library

Tags: wcf, testing, client

I am attempting to replace a WSE service with the WCF equivalent where the WSDL is provided externally.

First, I used svcutil  and wsdl to generate all the service and client classes (ATP, I'm only concerned with the service implementation.)  I generated an empty WCF Service Library project and replaced/renamed the `IService1.cs` with a class named for the interface `ServiceContractAttribute` generated. I then renamed the implementation class `Service1.cs` with the name of the implementation-class `JINDEXWcfListener.cs`. I removed the generated code from this class and created class definition `JINDEXWcfListener:[interface name]`.

The tool auto-generated the implementation of the interface. I used the single method adorned with `[OperationContractAttribute]` to put my local implementation code. I modified the default `app.config` generated to adjust the contract and service names as required.

When I start debug, I can see that the service is starting in the WTC. However, when the single operation is exposed, the is a red dot with a yellow question mark in front of the operation name. When I RC on the op name, I get "This operation is not supported in WCF Test client" with no additional information. What is wrong?

Comment: COuple of thoughts: are you using something other than http as your transport protocol? Or does your service method use some complex data type (more than a simple string, datetime etc.) ?? Those are often causes for the WCF Test Client to not be able to deal with the service

Comment: Don't depend on someone else's test client. Write unit tests of your own to test your services.

Answer (score 1):

WCFTestClient has quite a few limitations. I have fought "problems" for several hours that later turned out to be just WCFTestClient problems. Complex objects can give you a lot of grief, also any custom lists, etc such as a custom implementation of the IList interface. Try out WcfStorm. I think they have a free version and a trial version.